# dplyr mutate_at or mutate: how to append to a set of columns the value of one column

Tags: r, dplyr

Would like to use mutate_at over a range of columns w a function which accepts, as a 2nd argument, the value of some other column (v1 below). Any suggestions on how to do this with mutate_at?

```
df2 <- df1 %>%
  select(v1,c1:cN) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  # not working
  mutate_at(vars(c1:cN),funs(paste(.,v1,sep="-")))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you'd want to write your own function. Perhaps:

```
myFun <- function(x,y){
 paste(x,y, sep="-")
}
```

so then

```
df2 <- df1 %>%
  select(v1,c1:cN) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate_at(vars(c1:cN),funs(myFun(.,v1)))
```

Please provide a minimal working example for the `df1` data.